# __init__() got multiple values for argument trying to override forms.Form

Tags: django, forms, post

I'm trying to override my form to show a select with my data, my problem is when I try to send the form I get this error **init**() got multiple values for argument.

form.py

```
class ChangeMemberForm(forms.Form):
    coordinator = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None,label="Pesquisadores", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    def __init__(self,ubc, *args,**kwargs):
        super(ChangeMemberForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        ubc = Ubc.objects.get(id=ubc)
        self.fields['coordinator'].queryset = ubc.researchers.all()
```

view.py

```
def change_coordinator(request, pk):
    template_name =  'ubc/addmember.html'
    ubc = Ubc.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ChangeMemberForm(request.POST, ubc=ubc.id)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
        return redirect('accounts:account_detail', pk=request.user.id)
    form = ChangeMemberForm(ubc=ubc.id)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which you defined the parameters is:

```
def __init__(self, ubc, *args, **kwargs):
```

whereas you make a call to the `__init__` with:

```
form = ChangeMemberForm(request.POST, ubc=ubc.id)
```

So you called it with an unnamed first parameter, whereas the first parameter is `ubc`. So as a result, the `__init__` function received two values for the `ubc` parameter: `request.POST`, and `ubc.id`, and of course that does not make sense.

So you should replace it with:

```
form = ChangeMemberForm(ubc.id, request.POST)
```

So here that means that the first parameter (`ubc.id`) is redirected to the `ubc` parameter, and the second (`request.POST`) is the first parameter of the `*args`, which is a parameter of the `super().__init__` call.

Comment: You could also pass `data` as a named argument. Then the order doesn't matter. `ChangeMemberForm(data=request.POST, ubc=ubc.id)`

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The convention in django is to pass the form data as the first positional argument when you initialize a form.

The problem with your `ChangeMemberForm` is that `ubc` is declared as the first positional argument. So when you try to `ChangeMemberForm(request.POST, ubc=ubc.id)` both arguments would be interpreted as `ubc`, and python throws an exception.

When you subclass `Form` it's better to use only *named arguments* for any extra arguments required by your custom form class. With python 3, simply put `ubc` between `*args` and `**kwargs` in the `__init__` method signature.

```
class ChangeMemberForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, ubc, **kwargs):
        ...
```

(If you are using python 3.4 or earlier, you must include a default value for `ubc`, as mentioned by Willem in a comment)

If you have to support python 2, this syntax is not valid, and you must instead do something like this.

```
class ChangeMemberForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ubc = kwargs.pop('ubc')
        ...
```

Comment: This is actually invalid syntax for lower Python-3.x versions, since after `*args`, all unnamed parameters are exhausted, hence `ubc` needs to have a default value.

Comment: Thanks for your help